# PPTP Split Tunnelling

Tags: vpn, routing, pptp, tunnel

I have VPN on Linux with PPTP protocol. What I want to do is some kind of split tunnelling, which means that I need to use my real IP on some specific internet software, and use the VPN on the rest of internet.

I'm a beginner in Linux, but already asked some people and they said it can be done by a lot of methods, so I'm looking for easiest and fastest way. My VPN is installed by command line in `/etc/ppp/peers/vpnfile` and in `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/vpn-route`.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Here is the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/676527) for the similar question.

Comment: I think the best solution would be to create an Ubuntu virtual machine. Run your VPN client on this VM, and use the VM as your main OS. Run the specific application on the host OS. Simple.

Comment: Thank YOU Svetlana I hope this will work, from the first look I see that it is exactly what I need, but it will take sone time to do with my beginner linux knowledge.

Comment: if  the side of your "real ip" is not mocu, some simple host-routes would probably do the trick